# JSoup - exclude links

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm trying to exclude a list of links which I do not wish to crawl.

I could not find anything useful in the documentation that skips user requested urls.

I was, however, able to do it like this:

```
if(!(link.attr("href").startsWith("https://blog.olark.com") ||
                    link.attr("href").startsWith("http://www.olark.com")||
                    link.attr("href").startsWith("https://www.olark.com")||
                    link.attr("href").startsWith("https://olark.com") ||
                    link.attr("href").startsWith("http://olark.com"))) {
                this.links.add(link.absUrl("href")); //get the absolute url and add it to links list.                       }
```

Of course  this isn't a proper way to do it, so I wrapped the links in a List and tried to loop through it - however, it did not exclude a single link (code below):

```
List<String> exclude = Arrays.asList("https://blog.olark.com", "http://www.olark.com", "https://www.olark.com",  "https://olark.com", "http://olark.com");
            for (String string : exclude) {
                if(!link.attr("href").startsWith(string)) {
                    this.links.add(link.absUrl("href")); //get the absolute url and add it to links list.
                }
            }
```

So my question is: How do I make it avoid a list of urls? I'm thinking something similar to the second code block I've written, but I'm open for ideas or fixes.

Comment: [When exclusion is OR, inclusion is AND, aka DeMorgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws): you want to include a URL only if _every_ exclusion rule does not match it; it is not enough for a single rule to not match. Also, URL scheme and host names can be case-insensitive; are you sure yours are always lowercase?

Answer (score 0):

You can start with selecting and removing all the unwanted links. Then you can process your document without any checks.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class JsoupQuestion51072084 {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<a href=\"http://www.olark.com\"></a>" +
                "<a href=\"https://www.olark.com\"></a>" +
                "<a href=\"https://google.pl\"></a>" +
                "<a href=\"http://olark.com/qwerty\"></a>" +
                "<a href=\"https://olark.com/asdf\"></a>" +
                "<a href=\"https://stackoverflow.com\"></a>");
        System.out.println("Document before modifications:\n" + doc);

        // select links having "olark.com" in href.
        Elements links = doc.select("a[href*=olark.com]"); 
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Links to remove: " + links);
        System.out.println();

        // remove them from the document    
        for (Element link : links) {
            link.remove();
        }
        System.out.println("Document without unwanted links:\n" + doc);
    }
}
```

and the output is:

```
Document before modifications:
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <a href="http://www.olark.com"></a>
  <a href="https://www.olark.com"></a>
  <a href="https://google.pl"></a>
  <a href="http://olark.com/qwerty"></a>
  <a href="https://olark.com/asdf"></a>
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com"></a>
 </body>
</html>

Links to remove: <a href="http://www.olark.com"></a>
<a href="https://www.olark.com"></a>
<a href="http://olark.com/qwerty"></a>
<a href="https://olark.com/asdf"></a>

Document without unwanted links:
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <a href="https://google.pl"></a>
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com"></a>
 </body>
</html>
```